# Major problems sharing Ubuntu file with Samba

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I have a Ubuntu server running samba. IP Address 10.0.0.230

The same server is running VirtualBox with an instance of Ubuntu running samba. IP address 10.0.0.231

I have installed and reinstalled this entire setup four or five times.

From Windows 10, when I try to access samba on the bare medical machine, Windows reports it cannot access 10.0.0.230

However, Windows has no problem accessing 10.0.0.231 and seeing the share.

To further add to the confusion, a virtual copy Windows 10 sees 10.0.0.230 just fine.

Both ubuntu installs were done on the same day using the same ISO.

Since I have done several re-installs and the problem remains, I must be missing something.

I would appreciate any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain this, but after another windows reboot, windows seems to see the machine 10.0.0.230 and its shares.